# How to make a Tkinter table and widgets after?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, tkinter, widget

I am trying to make a table in Tkinter, and that works just fine. However, any widgets that are packed after the table are not generated and instead throw an error. How can I fix this?

This is the table code:

```
class Table:
  def __init__(self,root,rows,columns,lst):
    for i in range(rows):
      for j in range(columns):
        self.e = Entry(root, width=20, font=('Arial',16,))
        self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
        self.e.insert(END, lst[i][j])
```

This is the table generating code and after:

```
    thislist = [
      ("Title", name),
      ("Company Size", vol),
      ("Price per share", price)
    ]
    row_amount = 3
    col_amount = 2
    Table(root1, row_amount, col_amount, thislist)
    color = 'red' if percent < 0 else 'green' if percent > 0 else 'gray'
    Label(root1, text = str(percent) + '%', fg = color).pack()
```

And this is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 77, in search_function
    layout(name.upper())
  File "main.py", line 105, in layout
    Label(root1, text = str(percent) + '%', fg = color).pack()
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2396, in pack_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid
```

Comment: I recommend you search this site for that exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

The error obviously tells you that you have use both `.grid()` (all entry widgets inside `Table` class) and `.pack()` (label showing percentage) inside same parent container `root1` which is not allowed.

Suggest to put those entry widgets inside a frame instead and then *pack* this frame using `.pack()`:

```py
...
    # frame to hold the table
    frame = Frame(root1)
    frame.pack()
    # create table inside frame
    Table(frame, row_amount, col_amount, thislist)
    color = 'red' if percent < 0 else 'green' if percent > 0 else 'gray'
    Label(root1, text = str(percent) + '%', fg = color).pack()
...
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. Really helped a lot. However, I was wondering how to make the Entry Widget uneditable. I understand that it is supposed to be editable, but in this app, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @ProgramProdigy Then use `Label` instead of `Entry`.

Comment: But then I can't make it a grid, right? Could I have syntax?

Comment: Do you mean the border of the `Entry` widget? If yes, then there are also `borderwidth` (or `bd`) option and `relief` option that you can use in `Label` widget to simulate it.

Comment: I mean the general layout of it, with its grid format. It doesn't have the .grid method.

Comment: You can use `.grid()` on `Label` widget.